# chanaging an IF and Weekday formula into a vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to change the following function into VBA code. This will be part of a larger code.

```
IF((WEEKDAY($B12)=7),$I12,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more than 5 ways to do what you want, depending on what exactly do you need. One of these ways is to build a simple custom formula like this:

```
Public Function changingIfAndWeekday() As Variant

    Application.Volatile

    If Weekday(Range("B12")) = 7 Then
        changingIfAndWeekday = Range("I12")
    Else
        changingIfAndWeekday = ""
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like so (if you want the result on cell C12):

```
Sheet1.range("C12").value = "=IF(Weekday(Sheet1.range("B12").value = 7),Sheet1.range("I12").value,"")
```

You could also do it like so (if you want the result on a variable):

```
Variable = "=IF(Weekday(Sheet1.range("B12").value = 7),Sheet1.range("I12").value,"")
```